# Shopify Products API skipping items in pagination

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to create a paginated shopify products page. I'm using the `since_id` strategy laid out in their docs: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product#index-2020-10

Using this endpoint, as explained in the docs:

`/products.json?limit=5&since_id=${sinceId}`

sinceId being the id of the last product on the previous page

**The pagination seems to skip items.** And it doesn't seem to be a set number of products that it skips. Sometimes it is just one. Others it can be up to 10.

Obviously, that makes the "pagination" not work.

I am aware of the link in the header solution. But wanted to know if anyone has experienced this issue with `since_id`?

Answer (score 8):

The Shopify docs do not mention this, but if you do not add `since_id` in your initial request, it will order items by title, not id.

If you want your first page to match the ordering of other pages, use `since_id=0` on your first request. Note, the results will be ordered by id, not title. But they will* be ordered.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. I can't imagine how I'd have figured this out without